# Чтение файла частями C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Есть файл, пусть будет Script.ps1 powershell. Мне надо считать его частями и с каждой частью произвести некоторые(добавить в другой файл удаленно). Размер одной части допустим 1Кб.
Я понимаю, как делать, но что-то у меня совсем не выходит, помогите пожалуйста. Приблизительный код

```
byte[] buffer;
int size = 1024;
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
{
    buffer = new byte[size];            
    int count;                            
    int sum = 0;                          

    while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, size - sum)) > 0)
    {
        sum += count;
        //Дальше преобразую buffer в строку и уже пытаюсь работать со строкой
    }
}
```

Пытался тоже делать через количество кусков

```
long file_count = filestrim.Length / size;
//дальше в цикле запускаю считывание
```

но то ли я каретку не сдвигаю, то ли неправильно прописываю, не работает как надо(

Comment: Так и не должно работать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитайте описания метода Read, особенно про параметры метода https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx
Вы неправильно его используете. В вашем случае нужно fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, size). 
Т.к. FileStream поток, то каждый Read читает следующий кусок. "Сдвиг каретки" происходит автоматически